# finding probability of getting to state $1$ from $0$ in infinite state markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)$ be iid random variables such that $P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{6}$, $P(X_n=0)=\frac{1}{3}$, $P(X_n=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$, I want to prove that P(there is an integer $k$ such that $X_1+...+X_k=1$)=$\frac{1}{3}$.

Interpreting this as a Markov chain with states {$1,0,-1,-2,...$} we want the probability of getting to the state $1$ starting at state $0$: p_0, in the general probability of getting to the state $1$ starting at state $n$: $p_n$.

We have the following infinite set of equations:

$p_0=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}p_0+\frac{1}{2}p_{-1}$

$p_{-1}=\frac{1}{6}p_0+\frac{1}{3}p_{-1}+\frac{1}{2}p_{-2}$

$p_{-2}=\frac{1}{6}p_{-1}+\frac{1}{3}p_{-2}+\frac{1}{2}p_{-3}$

and in general:

$p_{-k}=\frac{1}{6}p_{-k+1}+\frac{1}{3}p_{-k}+\frac{1}{2}p_{-k-1}$

Solving this in terms of $p_0$ we get that $p_{-k}=p_0+p_0(\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{3^k})-(\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{3^k})=\frac{1}{2}(3p_0-1)-(\frac{1}{3})^k
(\frac{1}{2}p_0-\frac{1}{2})$

But right now $p_0$ could be arbitrary from $(0,1)$, we need one more equation/information.

$p_{-k}$ is decreasing when $k$ is increasing and it is bounded from below by $0$ so have a limit, can we use it somehow? What can we do to find out that $p_0=\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1

There are two missing pieces of information you need. The first is
$$
p_{-1}=p_0^2
$$
Why? In order to start from $-1$ and reach $1$, there needs to be a point where the Markov chain reaches $0$ in between. This is because the chain can only move upwards in increments of $+1$. Therefore, the event of moving $(-1\to 1)$ can be split into two events: moving from $(-1\to 0)$, and then moving from $(0\to 1)$. Furthermore, these two moves are independent, because of the Markov property. The symmetry of the process implies, $P(-1 \to 0)=P(0\to 1)=p_0$, so $P(-1 \to 1)=P(-1\to 0)\cdot P(0\to 1)=p_0^2$.

This equation, combined with $p_0=\tfrac16+\tfrac13p_0+\tfrac12p_{-1}$, gives a quadratic equation involving $p_0$ alone:
$$
p_0=\tfrac16 + \tfrac13p_0+\tfrac12 p_0^2
$$
Solving this, we conclude that either $p_0=1/3$ or $p_0=1$. How do we determine which of these is correct?

We can rule out the possibility of $p_0=1$ as follows. Assume that $p_0=1$. This means that starting from $0$, the Markov chain will certainly reach $1$. Once the chain reaches $1$, instead of stopping the process, let us allow the process to continue. Starting from $1$, since $p_0=1$, the chain will certainly move to $2$ (moving $1\to 2$ is equiprobable to moving $0\to 1$). Continuing, the chain will certainly move to $3$, then $4$, and so on, eventually reaching arbitrarily high positive numbers.

Let $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$. The strong law of large numbers implies that $S_n/n\to E[X_1]=-1/3$, with probability $1$. This means there exists a number $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $S_n<(-1/3+\epsilon)n$, for any $\epsilon>0$. Since $S_n$ is almost surely eventually negative, it cannot reach arbitrarily high numbers, contradicting the previous paragraph.

#### Method 2: Martingale convergence

Again, let $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$. Define
$$
M_n=3^{S_n}
$$
You can prove that $M_n$ is a martingale, with respect to the natural filtration. Indeed,
$$
\mathbb E[M_{n+1}\mid M_n] = \tfrac16 3^{S_n+1}+\tfrac 13 3^{S_n}+\tfrac 12 3^{S_n-1}=3^{S_n}=M_n.
$$
Furthermore, since $-\infty \le S_n\le 1$, we have $0\le M_n\le 3$. Since $M_n$ is bounded, $\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n$ exists with probability $1$, and the expected value of the limiting variable is the same as $E[M_0]$ (Martingale convergence theorem). Letting $M_\infty$ be the limiting variable, we have
$$
\mathbb E[M_\infty]=\mathbb E[M_0]=3^0=1
$$
On the other hand, $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ can only be $-\infty$ or $1$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n$ can only be $0$ or $3$. Therefore,
$$
\mathbb E[M_\infty]=p_0\cdot 3+(1-p_0)\cdot 0
$$
Combining the last two equations, you conclude $p_0=1/3$.

Comment: how $lim S_n$ can be $1$, in first method you showed that $S_n$ is is almost surely eventually negative?

Comment: In the first method, I modified the process so it continues even after hitting $1$, which ensures $\lim_n S_n=-\infty$. For the second method, I am using the original process which stops at $1$ when it hits $S_n=1$. Only the stopped process can hit $1$ and stay there, which allows $\lim_n S_n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have state space $\mathbb{Z}$, and state transitions $s\mapsto t$ with probabilities given by
\begin{align*}
P(t=s-1)&=\,\frac{1}{2}\\[4pt]
P(t=s)&=\,\frac{1}{3}\\[4pt]
P(t=s+1)&=\,\frac{1}{6}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
For integers $a,b,c$ with $a < b < c$, let $X(a,b,c)$ be the event that state $c$ is reached before state $a$, starting with state $b$.

In a conceptually similar way, for integers $b,c$ with $b < c$, let $X(-\infty,b,c)$ be the event that state $c$ is eventually reached, starting with state $b$.

Let $p(a,b,c)=P\bigl(X(a,b,c)\bigr)$ and let $p(-\infty,b,c)=P\bigl(X(-\infty,b,c)\bigr)$.

Note that by physical symmetry we have
$p(a-1,b-1,c-1)=p(a,b,c)$.

**Claim:**$\;p(-\infty,0,1)={\large{\frac{1}{3}}}$.

**Proof:**

For each positive integer $n$, let $v_n=p(-n,0,1)$.

We proceed to show, by induction on $n$, that
$$
v_n=\frac{3^n-1}{3^{n+1}-1}
$$
holds for all positive integers $n$.

For $n=1$ we have
\begin{align*}
&
p(-1,0,1)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}p(-1,0,1)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
v_1=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}v_1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
v_1=\frac{1}{4}
\\[4pt]
&
{\phantom{v_1}}
=\frac{3^1-1}{3^2-1}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so the base case $n=1$ is verified.

For the inductive step, assume that
$$
v_n=\frac{3^n-1}{3^{n+1}-1}
$$
holds for some positive integer $n$.

Then we get
\begin{align*}
&
p(-n-1,0,1)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}p(-n-1,-1,0)p(-n-1,0,1)           
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
p(-n-1,0,1)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}p(-n,0,1)p(-n-1,0,1)
\\[4pt]
&
\qquad
\Bigl(\,
\text{since $p(-n-1,-1,0)=p(-n,0,1)$}
\,\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
v_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}v_nv_{n+1}           
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
v_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4-3v_n}
\\[4pt]
&
{\phantom{v_{n+1}}}
=
\frac
{1}
{
4
-
3
\Bigl(
{\large{\frac{3^n-1}{3^{n+1}-1}}}
\Bigr)
}
\\[4pt]
&
{\phantom{v_{n+1}}}
=
\frac
{1}
{
4
-
3
\Bigl(
{\large{\frac{3^n-1}{3^{n+1}-1}}}
\Bigr)
}
\cdot
\frac
{3^{n+1}-1}
{3^{n+1}-1}
\\[4pt]
&
{\phantom{v_{n+1}}}
=
\frac
{3^{n+1}-1}
{
4(3^{n+1}-1)
-
3(3^n-1)
}
\\[4pt]
&
{\phantom{v_{n+1}}}
=
\frac
{3^{n+1}-1}
{
(4{\,\cdot\,}3^{n+1}-4)
-
(3^{n+1}-3)
}
\\[4pt]
&
{\phantom{v_{n+1}}}
=
\frac
{3^{n+1}-1}
{
3{\,\cdot\,}3^{n+1}-1
}
\\[4pt]
&
{\phantom{v_{n+1}}}
=
\frac
{3^{n+1}-1}
{3^{n+2}-1}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which completes the induction.

Then we get
\begin{align*}
p(-\infty,0,1)
&=
P\Bigl(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X(-n,0,1)\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
&=
\lim_{n\to\infty} P\Bigl(X(-n,0,1)\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
&\qquad
\Bigl(\,
\text{since}\;
X(-1,0,1)
\subset
X(-2,0,1)
\subset
X(-3,0,1)
\subset
\cdots
\,\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
&=
\lim_{n\to\infty}
v_n
\\[4pt]
&=
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{3^n-1}{3^{n+1}-1}
\\[4pt]
&=
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{3^n-1}{3^{n+1}-1}
\cdot
\frac{3^{-n}}{3^{-n}}
\\[4pt]
&=
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{1-3^{-n}}{3-3^{-n}}
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{1-0}{3-0}
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{1}{3}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as was to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I will prove that $\sum_{k} p_{-k}$ converges. Indeed,

\begin{align}
p_{-k} &\le \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \binom{2t+k+1}{t}\binom{2t+s+k+1}{s}\left(\frac16\right)^{t+k+1}\left(\frac12\right)^{t}\left(\frac13\right)^{s}\\
&= \left(\frac16\right)^{k+1}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\binom{2t+k+1}{t}\left(\frac1{12}\right)^{t} \sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \binom{2t+k+1+s}{s} \left(\frac1{3}\right)^s\\
&= \left(\frac16\right)^{k+1}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\binom{2t+k+1}{t}\left(\frac1{12}\right)^{t}\frac1{\left(1 - \frac13\right)^{2t+k+2}}\\
&= \left(\frac16\right)^{k+1}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\binom{2t+k+1}{t}\left(\frac1{12}\right)^{t}\frac1{\left( \frac23\right)^{2t+k+2}}\\
&= \left(\frac16\right)^{k+1}\left(\frac32\right)^{k+2}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\binom{2t+k+1}{t}\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)^{t}\\
&= \frac32 \left(\frac14\right)^{k+1}\frac1{\sqrt{1 - 4\times \frac{3}{16}}} \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\times\frac{3}{16}}}{2\times \frac{3}{16}}\right)^{k+1}\\
&= \frac32\times 2 \times \left(\frac14\right)^{k+1} \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{k+1}\\
&= 3\times\left(\frac13\right)^{k+1} = \left(\frac13\right)^{k}
\end{align}

This proves that the series $\sum_{k}p_{-k}$ converges and so $$\lim_{k\to \infty} p_{-k} = 0.$$